# Is my clock broken?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I understand that the Tamrielic cultures have their own names for days and months:

```
Tamrielic | Gregorian
---------------------
Sundas    | Sunday
Morndas   | Monday
Tirdas    | Tuesday
Middas    | Wednesday
Turdas    | Thursday
Fredas    | Friday
Loredas   | Saturday
=====================

Tamrielic        |  Gregorian
-----------------------------
Morning Star     |  January
Sun's Dawn       |  February
First Seed       |  March
Rain's Hand      |  April
Second Seed      |  May
Midyear          |  June
Sun's Height     |  July
Last Seed        |  August
Hearthfire       |  September
Frostfall        |  October
Sun's Dusk       |  November
Evening Star     |  December
============================
```

However, I've recently noticed that days seem to be ending/beginning at 3/4 PM instead of at midnight.  Is my clock broken?  Is there a way I can fix it?  Is this just another quirk in Tamriel's time keeping, or is this an undocumented feature in the game?

*Note:  I'm on a PS3.  Your console commands are no good here.*

Comment: You know, in some real-world calendars the day doesn't change at midnight either. For example, in the Hebrew calendar, a new day starts at sundown. Judging from Bethesda's track-record, thought, this may well be a bug :)

Comment: What is your time zone

Comment: @Jonas U.S. EST

Comment: Well, there goes my idea...

Comment: I once had a timing bug in the Blood on the Ice quest where something that was supposed to happen at 2am happened at 10 am the following day: I'd guess there are some bugs in their clock synchronization algorithm.

Comment: Randomly I wonder when the game seeds the clock, if it seeds it with the "You started playing at 3.15pm, every day will now end/start at 3.15pm". It'd be kind of stupid (causing everyone to be outta sync with each other) but wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: @djsmiley2k I agree that would be a bit of a ridiculous design choice, since time in-game is fairly independent of real-time otherwise.  I doubt that I started the game at 3-4 PM as you suggest but, unfortunately, I don't have the first auto-save anymore to verify.  I'm also pretty sure that the clock changed over at midnight *sometime* during my play history, but I can't clearly remember that I've ever really paid attention to it until now.

Comment: Skyrim is ridiculously buggy. You can't be this pedantic about it - I've had days of the week repeat even (Tirdas -> wait -> Tirdas). This isn't "Lord of the Rings" were you can take minutiae and discover some grand scheme the author/programmer had in mind.

Comment: no answer yet, bummer...

Comment: @desaivv No.  This means that, while waiting, Morndas becomes Tirdas at around 3/4 PM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely a bug.  A search of the Bethesda forums [yields this thread](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1291005-bug-game-day-not-in-sync-with-game-time/), specifically:

> Skyrim's game day cycle is NOT properly synchronized with the game's clock, with days changing at seemingly random times instead of 12:00 AM when it is supposed to. If this continues for extended periods, it can result in a seriously broken clock, which can have disastrous effects on the game's AI. Specifically, any packages that are tasked to be executed on a certain day will become broken because the game day is cycling at... say, two in the afternoon. The cause of this bug is currently unknown, but what is known is that it NEEDS to be fixed, as it IS game-breaking.
>
> There have also been sporadic reports from PS3 users saying this has happened to them, too, though I cannot confirm it for them. If that is the case, the problem might be that the game day cycle is frame-timed (though I can't say for sure what the problem is)."

[One poster thinks that](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1291005-bug-game-day-not-in-sync-with-game-time/page__view__findpost__p__19539729) it's a bug from the Fallout 3 engine (on which Skyrim is supposedly based):

> This is a bug carried over from the FO3 engine (not sure whether it was in Oblivion).
>
> It's not the calendar that's messing up, but the day of the week transition, the two of which seem to operate somewhat separately.
>
> So I think you'll find that the calendar has been managing fine, but it's the day of the week that will get all out of whack, changing at strange hours of the day.
>
> Maybe they'll actually fix it this time, but considering how long it's been lurking in the game engine, I'm not holding my breath."

Bonus round: [a plea from a fellow frustrated gamer @rockpapershotgun.com](http://www.rockpapershotgun.com/2011/12/08/hey-bethesda-could-you-fix-skyrim/) to fix Skyrim already.  Read the comments for some lovely puns!

Comment: The PS3 clock has nothing to do with in-game time.  In-game time is entirely independent of real-time.

Comment: I'm not proposing that skyrim uses your real time :)  However, are you certain that there is not an offset based on the PS3's clock?

Comment: Again, since Skyrim does not at all use the current time except for save file timestamps, this is still not relevant.

Comment: Point taken.  I'm going to lean toward bug ... Betheseda has had their share esp. on PS3.  Perhaps related to the save game bugs that a lot of PS3 users are complaining about.  [This thread](http://forums.bethsoft.com/topic/1291005-bug-game-day-not-in-sync-with-game-time/) points to it being a bug that's been around since day 1, with no fix in sight.  The OP suggested that "The problem might be that the game day cycle is frame-timed (though I can't say for sure what the problem is)."

Comment: That looks like as good a supporting reference as any.  Change your answer to refer to the issue being a known bug, and put the link in your answer.  I'll up-vote and accept for that.  Make sure to include any pertinent details (affected platforms, workarounds, Bethesda responses if there are any) in your answer.

Comment: Other pertinent details you may want to include are quests and other parts of the game that are at risk due to this bug.  I've seen some mentioned in the thread you linked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer update.  Seeing the first screenshot in the "bonus round" thread, it's nice to know I'm not the only one with the guy half-stuck into the ground outside Whiterun.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like the actual time the day changes tends to drift as you play the game.  Google found a few similar threads, but [this one](http://www.gamespot.com/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/forum/any-way-to-fix-the-day-changing-during-the-afternoon-anytime-that-isnt-midnight-61303772/) is the only one I found that was constructive.

Comment: Please at least summarize the key points in linked forum posts; they are notorious for link rot which will make your answer significantly less useful when it happens.

Comment: +1 to @NickT.  -1 to this answer, pending update.